# What was the "cast sea" or "molten sea" יָם מוּצָק specifically used for and by whom?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, kohen-priest, melachim-kings-book-of, levites-leviyim

What was the "cast sea" or "molten sea" יָם מוּצָק specifically used for and by whom?

It appears to be also known as "Yam sheasah Shlomo". https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.58b?lang=bi

What was it used for, I can imagine, it was, at least, for netillat yadayim, or was that its only use, if at all?

By "whom" I mean, was it only for the priests or for any levites (or could even an israelite use it)?

The "molten sea"-translation יָם מוּצָק is found at Melachim I - I Kings - Chapter 7. https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15891/showrashi/true

The "cast sea"-translation יָם מוּצָק is found at Melachim I - I Kings - Chapter 7. 
https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.7.23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi

I want to know what our rabbis of blessed memory wrote about it?

Update and Additions, based on an answer below:

The passage in the TaNaKh uses "rachtzah lakohanim" ( = "washing for the priests"), does it ever mean "mikveh [or tevillah] for the priests"? וְהַיָּ֕ם לְרָחְצָ֥ה לַכֹּהֲנִ֖ים בּֽוֹ https://www.sefaria.org/II_Chronicles.4.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

"Shlomo ha'Melech built a large, heavily ornamented Mikvah in the Beis ha'Mikdash for the use of the Kohanim." I saw this quote from here https://dafyomi.co.il/yoma/backgrnd/yo-in-058.htm , but I can't tell whether they are quoting a modern-day opinion, that it was built for a Mikvah for Kohanim, or if they are quoting a rabbi from blessed memory, and if so, who? Anybody knows?

Comment: The Yam Shel Shlomo formula for Pi

Comment: מוּצָ֑ק would be "cast", not "molten".

Comment: @simyou please provide your source, the above "molten" translation is from the chabad rashi site.

Comment: "molten" and "cast" share the same root, since we cast molten metal. I would understand a "molten pool" to mean  a pool holding molten metal, while a "cast pool" is made from molten metal. Sefaria also translates it as "cast", https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Kings.7.23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Answer (score 2):

The Yerushalmi (Yuma 3/8) [[Sefaria here on the ninth line in 19a]](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Yoma.19a.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes that it was used as a Mikvah for  Kohanim.

Comment: I can't find any reference to your linked passage.

Comment: It appears to be also known as "Yam sheasah Shlomo", but I can't see where it says in the Yerushalmi that it was used as a Mikvah for Kohanim. https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.58b?lang=bi

Comment: The passage in the TaNaKh uses "rachtzah lakohanim" (translated washing for the priests), does it ever mean "mikveh for the priests"?  וְהַיָּ֕ם לְרָחְצָ֥ה לַכֹּהֲנִ֖ים בּֽוֹ https://www.sefaria.org/II_Chronicles.4.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: "Shlomo ha'Melech built a large, heavily ornamented Mikvah in the Beis ha'Mikdash for the use of the Kohanim." I saw this quote from here ( https://dafyomi.co.il/yoma/backgrnd/yo-in-058.htm ), but I can't tell whether they are quoting a modern-day opinion, that it was built for a Mikvah for Kohanim, or if they are quoting a rabbi from blessed memory, and if so, who? Anybody knows?

Comment: Thanks to your phrase, "Mikvah for Kohanim", which I googled, and found this same phrase mentioned here: dailynach.com/malachim-alef/perek-summaries – But I have not found any answers to any of my above comments.

Comment: @ninamag - These are the words of the Yerushalmi "ר' שמעון בר כרסנא בשם ר' אחא הים בית טבילה לכהנים הוא "